# python multiprocessing large range

Tags: python, multiprocessing, range

I'm trying to understang how to use multiprocessing. My example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def my_func(x):
  print(mp.current_process().pid)
  time.sleep(2)
  return x**x

def main():
  pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
  result = pool.map(my_func, range(1, 10))

  print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

but if i've large range (from 1 to 5 million). Do i need to use `range(1,5000000)` or there is better solution? `my_func` will do some work with database.

Comment: This number 5million is a fixed number? Because I think there is no better way to do it. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction)

Comment: No, i select it from database and it will grow with time. What if i'll split range in smaller like `for i in range(1, 5000000, 1000): pool.map(my_func, range(i, i+ 1000))`?

Comment: I think you can just use with lange numbers, I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: I'm realising I've made a mistake. The pool and the processes will be fine, but it will try and return a list containing 5 million results, which may be a problem. You should probably unaccept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pool will have no problem dealing with a large range. It won't increase memory or CPU usage. It will still only create as many processes as you specify and each process will receive one number from the range at a time. The range will not be copied. There's no need to split it up.

Only caveat is that in Python 2 you should probably use `xrange`.